# Laravel:Call to a member function store() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel to get the request file from postman, however it seems Laravel cannot identify the file I posted. Following is my code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductImageController
{
public function update(Request $request, $id)
   {
        $path = $request->file('file')->store('images');
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product->img_url = $path;
        return $product->save() ?
            response(["error_code" => 0, $product]) :
            response(["error_code" => 1]);
   }
}
```

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lHpl.png)

[image]

Comment: Could you paste your HTML code ? I think you forgot the multipart="form/data" attribute on the form or you misspelled the input name.

Comment: @tete0148 It is a postman request. Read OP's question

Comment: Make sure the size of  your file does not exceed your PHP upload size limits. Also, try removing the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your method and check if there is any errors and check if form-data is selected in postman, Be careful with explicit Content-Type header. Better - do not set it's value, the Postman is smart enough to fill this header for you. BUT, if you want to set the Content-Type: multipart/form-data - do not forget about boudary field.:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
   $this->validate($request, [
      'file' => 'required|file'
   ]); 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $product->img_url = $request->file('file')->store('images');
        }
```

AND more info please follow this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-and-saving-avatars-to-the-storage-directory?page=1)

Hope this work for you !!!

Answer (score 0):

try to:
-Change Put to Post in postman also in your ROUTE 
-add this validator to your controller :

```
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[ 

        'file' => 'file|required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 401);
    }
```